# Disabling echo from webrick

Tags: ruby, logging, echo, ruby-1.9, webrick

How can I disable messages from webrick echoed on to the terminal? For the `INFO` messages that appear at the beginning, I was able to disable it by setting the `Logger` parameter so as:

```
s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
  Port: 3000,
  BindAddress: "localhost",
  Logger: WEBrick::Log.new("/dev/null"),
)
```

But I further want to disable the messages that look like:

> localhost - - [17/Jun/2011:10:01:38
>   EDT] "GET .... HTTP/1.1" 200 0
>   http://localhost:3000/ -> .....

when a request is made from the web browser.

Comment: Try setting AccessLog to false in the config parameters, that is as far as I can see by [the source code](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/classes/WEBrick/HTTPServer.html#M009708).

Comment: @Yet Another Geek I tried both setting it to false, then to nil, but it did not work.

Comment: @Yet Another Geek. When I set it to `[nil, nil]`, it worked. Your link helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Following the link to the [source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/classes/WEBrick/HTTPServer.html#M009708) and suggestion provied by Yet Another Geek, I was able to figure out a way. Set the `AccessLog` parameter to <strike>`[nil, nil]`</strike> `[]` (Changed following suggestion by Robert Watkins).

```
s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(
  Port: 3000,
  BindAddress: "localhost",
  Logger: WEBrick::Log.new("/dev/null"),
  AccessLog: [],
)
```

Comment: Actually, you're better off passing an empty array for the AccessLog - e.g. AccessLog: []

Passing in nils just results in an error, which you can't see because you've sent your error logs to /dev/null

Comment: Use `Logger: WEBrick::Log.new(File.open(File::NULL, 'w'))` for a cross-platform solution

Comment: For Rails edited `boot.rb`: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28968#issuecomment-327099731