# Disable Rack::CommonLogger without monkey patching

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, puma

So, I want to have completely custom logging for my `sinatra` application, but I can't seem to disable the `Rack::CommonLogger`.

As per the [sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) all I should need to do is add the following line (tried setting it to `false` as well):

```
set :logging, nil
```

to my configuration. This does not work however, and I still receive the Apache-like log messages in my terminal. So the only solution I've found so far is to monkey patch the damn thing.

```
module Rack
  class CommonLogger
    def call(env)
      # do nothing
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

Anyone got any ideas if it's possible to disable this without restorting to such matters?

Comment: You use `Sinatra::Application ` or `Sinatra::Base` for app?

Comment: I use `Sinatra::Base`.

Comment: from doc `"To avoid any logging middleware to be set up, set the logging setting to nil."`

Comment: I tried that, as well as setting it to ´false´. Didn't work.

Comment: and you try this `disable :logging`?

Comment: Tried it now, didn't work either I'm afraid. :-(

Comment: Just to be sure, you set these in a configure block which get executed?

Comment: Yeah, all other commands in the `configure do` block get executed.

Comment: What server are you using (thin, webrick etc.) and how are you starting the app (`ruby my_file.rb`, `rackup` etc.)?

Comment: I'm using `puma` and I start the server with the command `puma -p 3001`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puma [adds logging middleware](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/v2.8.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb#L113-116) to your app if you are in development mode and haven’t set the `--quiet` option.

To stop Puma logging in development, pass the `-q` or `--quiet` option on the command line:

```
puma -p 3001 -q
```

or if you are using a Puma config file, add `quiet` to it.

Comment: I am using Webrick and I still get logs on STDERR. Weird.

Answer (score 8):

I monkey patched the log(env, status, header, began_at) function, which is what gets called by rack to produce the apache style logs. We use jruby with logback so we have no use for all the custom logging that seems to pervade the ruby ecosystem. I suspect fishwife is initalizing the CommonLogger, which might explain why all my attempts to disable it or to configure it with a custom logger fail. Probably puma does something similar. I actually had two instances at one point. One logging with my custom logger (yay) and another one still doing its silly puts statements on stderr. I must say, I'm pretty appalled with the logging hacks in the rack ecosystem. Seems somebody needs a big cluebat to their heads.

Anyway, putting this in our config.ru works for us:

```
module Rack
  class CommonLogger
    def log(env, status, header, began_at)
      # make rack STFU; our logging middleware takes care of this      
    end
  end
end
```

In addition to that, I wrote my own logging middleware that uses slf4j with a proper MDC so we get more meaningful request logging.

Comment: Yay! After hours this is the only method that worked!

Comment: You don't need that. Just launch with `rackup --quiet`. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Rack includes a few middlewares by default when you `rackup` your application. It is defined in [this file](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/f9ad97fd69a6b3616d0a99e6bedcfb9de2f81f6c/lib/rack/server.rb#L253).

By default, as you mention, the logging middleware is enabled.

To disable it, just pass the option `--quiet` to `rackup`:

```
rackup --quiet
```

And the default loggin middleware will not be enabled.

Then, you can enable your own logging middleware without pollution by the default logger (named `CommonLogger`).

You can also add `#\ --quiet` to the top of your `config.ru` file to avoir always typing `--quiet`, but [this behaviour is now deprecated](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/1639).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not Sinatra what is writing to STDOUT or STDERR, but your webserver. **Puma** can be started with *-q* (quiet) option as noted by @matt. When using **webrick** make sure the *AccessLog* configuration variable is an empty array, otherwise it will also be logged on your standard output.

[Disabling echo from webrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387087/disabling-echo-from-webrick)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the top results. So this probably more of a message to my future self the next time I'm annoyed to death about sinatra/puma not shutting up. But to actually get a silent start up:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :server, :puma
    set :quiet, true
    set :server_settings, Silent: true
  end
end
```